# Avoiding N+1 in model instance methods by using sort_by instead of order

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app is a CRM for teachers where a **Teacher** belongs_to an **Account** that has_many **Students** who HABTM **PhoneNumbers** through **CallablePhoneNumbers** (since, IRL siblings can share one phone number).

*(Aside: As a possible complicating factor, PhoneNumbers is Polymorphic. Both Teachers and Students are "Callable"...)*

**My Issue:** I'm trying to avoid N+1 in a students_list view. When viewing a list of 900 students and some metadata, the database hits are pretty terrifying.

**app/models/student.rb**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  has_many :phone_numbers, through: :callable_phone_numbers, as: :callable_phone_numbers

  ...

  def last_messaged_at
    self.phone_numbers.order(:last_received_message_at).last.try(:last_received_message_at)
    # :last_received_message_at is a simple DateTime in the database
  end

  ...

end
```

When I'm showing a list of students I want to show the last_messaged_at method as a status alongside the student, and I'm attempting to avoid N+1 via .includes()

**app/controllers/dashes_controller.rb**

```
class DashesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_teacher

  def show
    @teacher = Teacher.includes(account: [{students: [:phone_numbers, :grade_level, :student_groups]}, :grade_levels]).includes(:student_groups).find(@current_teacher.id)
  end

end
```

Yes, there are a lot of other associations in there. I'm focusing this question exclusively on PhoneNumbers, though feedback about my use of .includes() would not be unwelcome, since it does look convoluted.

In the console, I can go...

```
pry(main)> t = Teacher.includes(account: [{students: [:phone_numbers, :grade_level, :student_groups]}, :grade_levels]).includes(:student_groups).find(3)
  Teacher Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "teachers".* FROM "teachers" WHERE "teachers"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Account Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" IN (3)
  Student Load (8.2ms)  SELECT "students".* FROM "students" WHERE "students"."account_id" IN (3)
  CallablePhoneNumber Load (7.3ms) ... ETC

pry(main)> t.account.students.first.phone_numbers
=> [#<PhoneNumber:0x007fddcc59ac98
  id: 15,
  number: ... ETC
```

...to get phone_numbers without an additional **PhoneNumber Load**. However, when I...

```
pry(main)> t.account.students.first.last_messaged_at
  PhoneNumber Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "phone_numbers".* FROM "phone_numbers" INNER JOIN "callable_phone_numbers" ON "phone_numbers"."id" = "callable_phone_numbers"."phone_number_id" WHERE "callable_phone_numbers"."callable_id" = ? AND "callable_phone_numbers"."callable_type" = ?  ORDER BY "phone_numbers"."last_received_message_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["callable_id", 3], ["callable_type", "Student"]]
=> Thu, 06 Aug 2015 18:01:12 UTC +00:00
```

I'm unexpectedly forced to ping the database again, when I would've thought those PhoneNumbers were already in memory.

I felt like an instance method was most appropriate for this, but maybe it should be a helper that I pass the Collection of Phone Numbers to? Even if that's the case, it's still unclear to me why the instance method can't "see" the loaded PhoneNumbers.

Comment: i think your ordering clause `order(:last_received_message_at)` in the method it is re sending the query. can you try removing that order clause from the method and see if it still make a seperate query.?

Comment: I could see that logic making sense. However, the .order() logic is necessary (since the last created may not be the most recently messaged). And, it didn't actually prevent the additional queries.

Comment: what if you replace your method line with this. will this help. `self.phone_numbers.sort_by {|pn| pn.last_received_message_at}.last.try(:last_received_message_at)`

Comment: That didn't work either. Still re-queried. It is interesting though. The "bad" version of the query really wants a where-clause-style "callable_type" = ?. The #includes version omits the where even though it's the same association being referenced. I wonder if that's why Rails doesn't see it as being already-loaded...

Comment: HOLD THE PHONE. Actually, I got sort_by to work. (I also had to add an additional catch-all to the sort_by block to address nils. I'm not sure what exactly I was doing yesterday that led me to get the re-query, but I'm golden now. `self.phone_numbers.sort_by { |pn| pn.last_received_message_at || Time.now - 20.year }.last.try(:last_received_message_at)`

Comment: If you add this as an answer below, I'll gladly accept it. :)

Comment: perfect.. adding the query you wrote in the comment to the answer as that worked perfectly for you. i hope you dont mind.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try `sort_by` if you have already eager loaded the associations.

```
self.phone_numbers.sort_by { |pn| pn.last_received_message_at || Time.now - 20.year }.last.try(:last_received_message_at)
```